# Figuring out how to mock the window size changing for a react component test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

So basically when the component mounts, I have an event listener listen for resize events. It toggles the isMobileView state and then passes it into the children as a prop. So it's imperative that this works and is tested. I'm fairly new to testing and I'm trying to figure out a way I can write a test that resizes the window and makes all the logic happen and test that it executed how it should.

Here is the code -

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setMobileViewState()
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.setMobileViewState.bind(this));
}

setMobileViewState() {
    if(document.documentElement.clientWidth <= this.props.mobileMenuShowWidth) {
        this.setState({ isMobileView: true })
    } else {
        this.setState({ isMobileView: false })
    }
}
```

I know the code works, but I want to write a test for it. Basically just something that makes sure the state changes correctly.

Answer (score 89):

Using Jest and Enzyme you can do the following. Jest has JSDOM baked in. In your tests Jest provides the `window` object and it is represented by `global` (I think that the default `window.innerWidth` set by Jest is 1024px):

```
test('Test something when the viewport changes.', () => {

    // Mount the component to test.
    const component = mount(<ComponentToTest/>);

    ...

    // Change the viewport to 500px.
    global.innerWidth = 500;

    // Trigger the window resize event.
    global.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

    ...

    // Run your assertion.
});
```

Comment: according to docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth, innerWidth is read only. should we use window.resizeBy(x, y); instead?

Comment: I'm on Jest 23.6.0 and it works for me, maybe needs an upgrade ‍♂️

Comment: Confirmed working still in Jest 24.1.0 as well.  the `resizeBy` would make sense to use but Jest does not implement that and the `innerWidth` is not read only

Comment: It seems this no longer works: `Property 'innerWidth' does not exist on type 'Global'`

Comment: Working fine in Jest 21.2.1

Comment: i tried setting innerWidth on window object but my @media css query didn't seem to kick in for the test. does this only work for 'global' object in node.js, or should it work for 'window' object in browser too?

Comment: I recommend putting this in a `beforeEach(() => { global.innerWidth = 500; global.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))'; });` so that you have control of the `window.innerWidth` for subsequent specs.

Comment: would we need to reset the window width after the test is run? would be better to mock the property getter for the particular test instead of changing it directly on global

Comment: Works fine in 2022, using `@testing-library/jest-dom: 5.16.2`.

Comment: Interesting @crevulus It does not work for me, my tests just hang. Using 5.16.1 and Node 14.

Answer (score 44):

If you are getting the typescript error message

> Cannot assign to 'innerWidth' because it is a read-only property.

Try:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'innerWidth', {writable: true, configurable: true, value: 200})
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this line:

```js
window = Object.assign(window, { innerWidth: 500 });
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who's using `react-testing-library`, there is a native way to achieve it using [fireEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/#fireevent) as well.

```
  import { fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
  ...

  it('should resize', () => {
    window.innerWidth = 500;
    fireEvent(window, new Event('resize'));

    // your test here
  });
```

Comment: NB: this will only work in JS.  
window.innerWidth is a readonly property - you will get build errors.
See @Lauren Madigan's annswer above if using TS

Comment: Don't see any TS requirement in the question.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me with testing library:

```
  it('should resize', () => {
    const altImage = 'test'

    window.innerWidth = 500

    fireEvent(window, new Event('resize'))

    waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByAltText(altImage)).not.toBeInTheDocument()
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jest.spyOn(window.screen, "width", "get").mockReturnValue(1000);
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way with testing library:

```
function fireResize(width) {
  window.innerWidth = width;
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}

it('some test', async () => {
  ....
  await waitFor(() => {
   fireResize(500);
  });
  ....
});
```

Source: https://medium.com/@dawchihliou/testing-react-hooks-6d3ae95cd838