# How to test that a media query css applies to an element upon screen resize using jest and enzyme in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, responsive-design, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test the responsiveness of the application I am building in reactjs using jest and enzyme. How can I do that?

I have a sidebar which transitions left and disappears when the screen size is less than or equal to 1024px. I went through this - [Figuring out how to mock the window size changing for a react component test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868042/figuring-out-how-to-mock-the-window-size-changing-for-a-react-component-test) stackoverflow question to simulate/mock a screen resize. Then I tried using DOM functions like getComputedStyle to see if the css rule for transition is applied to the side bar. But I can't find the transform rule I applied. When I selected the side bar, stored it as a global element and did getComputedStyle over it in the browser console, it worked. What am I doing wrong?

**test.ts**

```
describe('App', () => {

  let mountedApp: any;
  const props: RouteComponentProps = {
   ...
  } as RouteComponentProps;

  const initialState = {
    ...
  };

  // Function that returns a new App mounted
  const newApp = ((route: string) => {
    if (!mountedApp) {
      props.location.pathname = route;
      mountedApp = mount(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[route]}>
          <Provider store={configureStore([thunk])(initialState)}>
            <App {...props} />
          </Provider>
        </MemoryRouter>,
        { attachTo: document.body }
      );
    }
    return mountedApp;
  });

  it('Expect the side bar to disappear and menu icon to appear for smaller screen size', () => {
    const wrapper = newApp('/');
    let container = wrapper.find(NavDrawer).find(Drawer);
    expect(container.props().classes.paper).toEqual('nav-drawer-paper drawer-close');
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'innerWidth', {writable: true, configurable: true, value: 1024});
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    // expect(container.find(Drawer)).toHaveStyleRule('transform', 'translate3d(-240px, 0, 0)');
    let element = container.getDOMNode().children[0];
    let HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('drawer-close')[0];
    console.log('dom element', window.getComputedStyle(HTMLElement));
    console.log('element style', window.getComputedStyle(element));
  });
});
```

NavDrawer is the Component I wrote inside which I used the material ui Drawer component. To that component I applied the styles.

**NavDrawer.ts**

```
class NavDrawer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        className='nav-drawer'
        variant='permanent'
        anchor='left'
        classes={{paper: `nav-drawer-paper${this.props.isDrawerClose ? ' drawer-close' : ''}`}}
      >
        ...
        ...
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

When the side bar disappears, I show the menu icon on the top bar. By clicking on it the user can open or close the side bar in smaller screens. `this.props.isDrawerClose` says if the drawer is opened by the user or not. It is `true` by default.

**style.less**

```
.nav-drawer {
  width: 240px;
  z-index: 1295;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  .nav-drawer-paper {
    border-right-width: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    padding-top: 68px;
    width: 240px;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);      
  }  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  .nav-drawer {
    .nav-drawer-paper {
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.38);
    }
    .drawer-close {
      transition: all 300ms ease;
      transform: translate3d(-240px, 0, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

I found something called `toHaveStyleRule` but I'm not able to use it(you can see it commented in the test.ts file) because it gives tslint error `Property 'toHaveStyleRule' does not exist on type 'Matchers<any>'`

I also tried using the web dom api to get the element and check styles as I did in the browser console but still not working. Initially the `document.getElementsByClassName` was returning an empty array. So I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694975/jest-enzyme-using-mount-document-getelementbyid-returns-null-on-componen) stackoverflow question and added `{ attachTo: document.body }` option in the mount. I could retrieve the DOM element but not able to get the same results as in browser.

In browser, following is what I did and got.

I did

```
ele = document.getElementsByClassName('drawer-close')[0]
window.getComputedStyle(ele).transform
```

which gave
`"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)"`

After resizing the screen to less than 1024px, it gave
`"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -240, 0)"`

I expected the same to happen in the browser but when I consoled computerStyle.transform, it gave an empty string.