# Set size of window in Jest and jest-dom and jsdom

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jest-dom

I test the height of the window in Jest with jest-dom and jsdom.

With this code :

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

describe('test window height'), () => {
  test('test the height'), () => {
    expect(window.innerHeight).toBe(150) // 150 is an arbitrary value for testing the test ! 
   }) 
 })
```

The result is an error that say :

Expected: 150

Received: 768

With innerWidth, the received value is 1024

That is great, it means that the size of window is testable with Jest and jest-dom.

But where does 768 and 1024 come from ? Is it the default values and will always be ? Is it configurable and how?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The 768 and 1024 is a default, Jest is configuring jsdom for your test with.

You can overwrite window.innerHeight in your test. But TypeScript says no, because window is an unwritable member.

For me `Object.defineProperty` works as expected with TypeScript.

So with **JEST** this test should pass green:

```
describe('test window height', () => {
  it('test the height',
    () => {
      Object.defineProperty(window, 'innerHeight', {
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        value: 150,
      });

      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

      expect(window.innerHeight).toBe(150);
    });
});
```

Example of use of Object.defineProperty with TS found here: [How to test that a media query css applies to an element upon screen resize using jest and enzyme in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537059/how-to-test-that-a-media-query-css-applies-to-an-element-upon-screen-resize-usin)